# ipad and xampp connection

Tags: ipad, xampp

I'm having problems connecting to local host on ipad. Main problem is that it sometimes connects and sometimes don't. My computer is part of a wireless network, and it's only one where this problems occurs.

I've tried to turn off win 7 firewall, avira antivirus, spybot s&d, dropbox, gtalk etc. but it still returned "cannot connect to page" error.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

have u tried the IP (http://192.xxx.x.xxx) instead of localhost?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 192.168.1.34/mysite . But most of the time it doesn't work. If for example 192.168.1.38/mysite is typed, it works all the time, but that's different computer.